# Count of fields when populated using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, arraylist

I have a recommendation form with few checkboxes and dropdowns.

I would like to do is to count the number of fields that have been populated by the user using JavaScript or Jquery. I have written the script in a lengthy format, and it works, but is there a way to shorten or simplify the below script. I am a beginner level.

```
 function RecomendationCount() {
     var Rec01 = 0;
     var Rec02 = 0;
     var Rec03 = 0;
     var Rec04 = 0;
     var Rec05 = 0;
     var Rec06 = 0;
     var Rec07 = 0;
     var Rec08 = 0;
     var Rec09 = 0;
     var Rec10 = 0;
     if (document.getElementById("Q68I1065").value != "") {
         Rec01 = 1 //FluidRegimeChanges
     }
     if (document.getElementById("Q81I10781").checked == true) {
         Rec02 = 1 //Ue
     }
     if (document.getElementById("Q82I10791").checked == true) {
         Rec03 = 1 //VenousLactate
     }
     if (document.getElementById("Q83I10801").checked == true) {
         Rec04 = 1 //VenousBicarbonate
     }
     if (document.getElementById("Q84I10811").checked == true) {
         Rec05 = 1 //Fbc
     }
     if (document.getElementById("Q86I10831").checked == true) {
         Rec06 = 1 //BloodCultures
     }
     if (document.getElementById("Q87I10841").checked == true) {
         Rec07 = 1 //UrineCytometryCulture
     }
     if (document.getElementById("Q88I10851").checked == true) {
         Rec08 = 1 //RenalUltrasound
     }
     if (document.getElementById("Q89I10861").checked == true) {
         Rec09 = 1 //OtherImaging
     }
     if (document.getElementById("Q90I10871").checked == true) {
         Rec10 = 1 //SuspendPlannedContrastImaging
     }
     var totalRec = (Rec01 + Rec02 + Rec03 + Rec04 + Rec05 + Rec06 + Rec07 +
         Rec08 + Rec09 + Rec10);
     y = document.getElementById("test");
     y.innerHTML = totalRec;
 }
```

below is the html

```
    <table>
                            <tr >
                                <td >Fluid regime changes</td>
                                <td>

                                 <select name="Q68I1065" id="Q68I1065" onclick="RecomendationCount();" >
                                        <option value=""></option>
                                        <option value="0">None</option>
                                        <option value="1">Start or increase oral</option>
                                        <option value="2">Decrease or stop oral</option>
                                        <option value="3">Start or increase IV</option>
                                        <option value="4">Decrease or stop IV</option>
                                        <option value="9">Other</option>
                                 </select>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="Q81I1078" id="Q81I10781" value="1" onclick="RecomendationCount();">
                                    <label >U&E </label></input>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="Q82I10791" id="Q82I10791" value="1" onclick="RecomendationCount();">
                                    <label >VenousLactate</label></input>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="Q83I10801" id="Q83I10801" value="1" onclick="RecomendationCount();">
                                    <label >VenousBicarbonate</label></input>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="Q84I10811" id="Q84I10811" value="1" onclick="RecomendationCount();">
                                    <label >Fbc</label></input>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="Q86I10831" id="Q86I10831" value="1" onclick="RecomendationCount();">
                                    <label >BloodCultures</label></input>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="Q87I10841" id="Q87I10841" value="1" onclick="RecomendationCount();">
                                    <label >UrineCytometryCulture</label></input>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="Q88I10851" id="Q88I10851" value="1" onclick="RecomendationCount();">
                                    <label >RenalUltrasound</label></input>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="Q89I10861" id="Q89I10861" value="1" onclick="RecomendationCount();">
                                    <label >OtherImaging</label></input>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="Q90I10871" id="Q90I10871" value="1" onclick="RecomendationCount();">
                                    <label >SuspendPlannedContrastImaging</label></input>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
```

Your help and suggestion is much appreciated. 
thanks

Comment: Can you post the HTML with checkboxes, pls ?

Comment: I have posted the html, please see updated post

Comment: Take a look to my answer

Comment: Any suggestions using javascript instead of jquery.? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put a common class to all your checkboxes (for example "CheckboxesToCount", you can use this line of code to count how many checkboxes are checked:

```
$(".CheckboxesToCount:checked").length
```

With Javascript + example of HTML:

```
<script>
    var count = 0;
    function updateCount(checkbox) {
        if(checkbox.checked) {
            count++;
        } else {
            count--;
        }
    }

    function count()
    {
        alert(count);
    }
</script>
<input type="button" value="Count" onClick="count();">
<input type="checkbox" onClick="updateCount(this);"><br>
<input type="checkbox" onClick="updateCount(this);"><br>
<input type="checkbox" onClick="updateCount(this);"><br>
<input type="checkbox" onClick="updateCount(this);"><br>
<input type="checkbox" onClick="updateCount(this);"><br>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use css selectors to find the `:checked` `input`s. This will return an `array`, which you can check the `length` property.

```
document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length;
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/t10zcxse/)

Answer (score 0):

with jQuery this should do the job:

```
var number = $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").add(
    $("select[value!='']")
).length
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot solutions with jQuery right now.

And those will do the job if you just want to count the selected boxes. But maybe you want to do something else with your data later. Then the "length"-solutions are not enough anymore.
You asked to refactore your code to make it bit more clean. So I just did a bit of this, this may not be the best or the simplest solution, but it is *your* code without ignoring [DRY-principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)

The code is not tested, but should work.

```
function RecomendationCount() {
    var checkBoxes = {
        "Q68I1065" : 0,
        "Q81I10781" : 0,
        "Q82I10791" : 0,
        "Q83I10801" : 0,
        "Q84I10811" : 0,
        "Q86I10831" : 0,
        "Q87I10841" : 0,
        "Q88I10851" : 0,
        "Q89I10861" : 0,
        "Q90I10871" : 0
    };
    checkBoxes = check(checkBoxes);

    var totalRec = countChecked(checkBoxes);
    y = document.getElementById("test");
    y.innerHTML = totalRec;
}

function check (checkBoxes) {
    var updatedArray = checkBoxes;
    for (var key in checkBoxes) {
        if (document.getElementById(key).checked == true) {
            updatedArray[key] = 2;
        }
        updatedArray[key] = 1;
    }
    return updatedArray;
}

function countChecked(checkBoxes) {
    var count = 0;
    for (var key in checkBoxes) {
        count+= checkBoxes[key];
    }
    return count;
}
```